# XGBRegressor model generates many more trees than a similar XGBClassifier model

Tags: python, scipy, xgboost

I am doing a boosted classification trees vs. boosted regression trees comparison in python using xgboost as partly a project for a client and partly an internal experiment. I am using the exact same data but am modeling different targets.

For the boosted classification trees model I transpose the data to give me a Good/Bad flag as the target and use the probability of someone being good/bad as the sample weight.

We have used this approach successfully on other use cases, getting quite accurate models with good point predictions.  By using early stopping I end up with a model with around 1000 estimators after tuning parameters etc.

For the boosted regression trees model I am using the sample weight (basically a probability of someone being good/bad) as a target and end up with ~12000 estimators in the final model.

Why is there such a large discrepancy between the continuous target and the discrete target in terms of model complexity?